# Render angular2 Component from javascript and get html in return

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to execute angular2 component from JavaScript and get generated HTML in return?

I would like to write a function in plain JavaScript/JQUERY which should execute angular2 component and returns generated HTML.

For example: something like

```
var html = executeAngular2ComponentAndReturnHtml('componentName');
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Why do you want to write the function in plain JS if you already have angular?

Comment: i basically want to write a wrapper around angular2 application, wrapper can be included by the user from cdn and can be used easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `innerHTML` attribute to do that. Bind it to a property of your component class like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="customHtml">  // note the casing of innerHTML.
</div>
```

In your `Component` code:

```
this.customHtml = executeAngular2ComponentAndReturnHtml('componentName');
```

**Important**: You may also want to mark your HTML as trusted so that Angular2's DOM sanitizer does not remove parts of it. For this, please see [angular 2 html binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)